# How to restrict my endpoint api discovery

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have an endpoint api at project-id.appspot.com. It is possible for anyone to see all methods (but not to run them) via google api explorer. How to disbable it? I don't want to tell publically what my api is.

Answer (score 0):

The discovery document is used by the JS API client library, and as such was not designed to be disabled. There's currently no support for that.